# Override custom content page markup Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, overriding, content-type

Although I've seen some 'clean' answers on this topic here, it still doesn't work in my case, which is the following: being in Drupal 7 with a completely customized theme, I have created a custom content with the machine name cco_product. I want to override the page markup for the page generated for this content type. I have tried, as per the documentation, 
page--cco_product.tpl.php in the tmemes folder, based on /module/system/page.tpl.php, but my  Hello world on top of this file doesn't show up.
Thanks for help

Comment: Done it, is node--cco_product.tpl.php. And, from own experience, clear the cache before testing if override works!!

Answer (score 1):

First, try clean your cache, if did't help, i can advise to look into the an array of templates for your page. Maybe one of your modules or your custom theme overrides array of templates like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {   
   //Add multiple suggestions for pages based on Node
   if(arg(1) == 3) {  //For node 3
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'page__contact';
   } if(arg(1) == 4) {   //For node 4
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  'page__about';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's true getting info from suggestions. I was referring to finding a Drupal kind of naming convention for these cases. Eventually I've found the right matching as node--product.tpl.php, by chance quite quickly.